# PHP Remove Square Brackets from Array Key

Tags: php, arrays, key

**Answer:**

So my issue turned out to be with the $eventValue and not the key. I was assuming the key was wrapped in brackets when it was added to the $days array but that was not the case. var_export showed me what really gets added to the array.

To solve the problem, I removed the enclosing quotes from the $eventValue as well as the trailing , comma.

**Below is the original question:**

Apologies as I do not know a whole lot of PHP, but I am trying to achieve something that I hope someone here can help with.

I have a loop that is finding specific days of a month to highlight on a calendar. In order for the calendar to highlight a specific day and wrap it in a class as well as a link tag, I need the array to be in this format:

```
$days = array(

    2 => array('/weblog/archive/2004/Jan/02', 'linked-day'),
    3 => array('/weblog/archive/2004/Jan/03', 'linked-day'),
    8 => array('/weblog/archive/2004/Jan/08', 'linked-day'),
    22 => array('/weblog/archive/2004/Jan/22', 'linked-day'),

);
```

Within my loop, I have these two variables:

```
$eventDay = substr("$str", -2, 2);
$eventValue = "array('http://example.com', 'linked-day'),";
```

and at the end of my loop I have this:

```
$days[$eventDay] = $eventValue;
```

The problem is, when I print_r ($days), my $eventDay key is wrapped in [] square brackets and so the day cannot be found by the calendar. I need to find a way to prevent it from being wrapped in brackets.

Perhaps I am approaching this all wrong. If someone has some suggestions I would really appreciate it.

I am using Keith Devens' PHP Calendar script to do this:

http://keithdevens.com/software/php_calendar

Thanks!

**Full code:**

http://pastie.org/5503664

Comment: Where is `$str` defined/assigned?

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump()` instead of `print_r()` ?

Comment: Could you show us the full code? The portion you showed isn't enough (eg, what is `$str`?). What is your actual goal for this snippet?

Comment: Can you give us a sample of `print_r` please...

Comment: Apologies for not posting full code. I have updated the original question with a link at the bottom to the code. Also, here is what print_r spits out: http://pastie.org/5503673

Comment: @Eugen here is the var_dump: http://pastie.org/5503681

Comment: @beefchimi Sorry, ofcourse I meant `var_export()` ... is this the beginning of Alzehimer's?

Comment: When you do a var_dump (or equivalent) the array key is shown wrapped in square braces so that you can see it clearly.... it doesn't actually contain square braces in the key... however, you're quoting the array value.... do you really mean to do that?

Comment: @Eugen, ah, here is the var_export: http://pastie.org/5503735 So perhaps the brackets are not my problem then? Should I be removing the comma at the end of the $eventValue variable and then focusing on how to prevent the value from being wrapped in single quotes? Also, I am not sure why the first key (09) is getting wrapped in single quotes while the others are not.

Comment: @Mark and Eugene, ok, so I removed the comma from $eventValue as well as the enclosing quotes, and it works now! I have to now find if a value begins with a 0 and if so, remove it, but that is itself another question. Big thanks to everyone who submitted suggestions!

Comment: "09" is a string .. cast (or add to zero) to be sure it is int. But your problem is elsewhere, see my upcoming answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
$eventValue = "array('http://example.com', 'linked-day'),";
```

with

```
$eventValue = array('http://example.com', 'linked-day');
```

in line 44 of the pastie